# How could I show current GIT branch in my Vue 3 Web application

Tags: javascript, git, vue.js

I like to have a visual cue of the current GIT branch I am working on and have that set up in my IDE (I currently use VIM but I know VSCode also does this). I like/need it so much that I would really also like to see it in my development build when serving locally.

I currently do this manually with a label that I update by hand each time I create a new branch to work on. However, I often forget to do this and subsequently confuse myself.

I'm wondering whether it would be possible to pull this information from GIT and show it in my UI in the same way VSCode does?

Specifically I am using Vue 3 and Typescript but I guess that is not super relevant to the general problem.

Anyone have a feel of how you would do this?

Comment: My advice would be _not_ to track branch name in a file. This won't help. (in case you thought about doing that)

Comment: Are you using Webpack to build your app?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Webpack as a bundler, there is a [git-commit-info-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/ewendlick/git-commit-info-webpack-plugin#readme) which can write some Git info (branch name, last commit date/hash/author) into a json file on each build.

Just import the json file into your app and use it....

Comment: I am using Webpack. I'll check this out and give it a try.